# What is the difference between /proc/version and /etc/redhat-release?

Tags: linux, redhat

What is the difference between /proc/version and /etc/redhat-release?

They showed different versions...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One tells you about the kernel. The other tells you about the distribution.

- `/proc/version` has the linux kernel version (and [some other stuff](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-proc-version.html)).
- `/etc/redhat-release` has the version/release of Redhat that you're using.

If you upgrade your kernel, then `/proc/version` will change but `/etc/redhat-release` won't.